# Why is a second connection for a PowerAutomate custom connector failing?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, mailerlite

I have created a custom connector to link to an email marketing provider (MailerLite). (This is my first attempt at a custom connector).

The connector works fine with - I have tested within the creation process and used successfully for 4 months or so in an active Flow.

I have now tried to connect the same connector to a different account with the provider, by creating a new connection (on the same custom connector) with a new API key for the different account. I've made no other changes. When I use this connection, my connection is 'unauthenticated'.

Is there a limit on the number of connections for a custom connector? Is there a way I can enable a connection to this other account?

I have tried updating the API (getting a new key) to ensure there was no error with the key for this new account. I have also tried re-creating the custom connector with a different user account (in the same environment).